# Check if list2 contains list1

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This function is supposed to check if the list1 is contained in the list 2 and and in that case return 1. I'm not sure why I always get output 0. 
All feedback is welcome.

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} *list;


int contains (list l1, list l2)
{
  int check;
  while(l1 != NULL){
    check = 0;

    while(l2 != NULL){
      if(l1->data == l2->data)
        check = 1;

      l2 = l2->next;
    }

    if(check == 0)
      return 0;

    l1 = l1->next;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: did you walk it with a debugger?  you are not reseting the l2 pointer to the start of the list when checking elements of l1 past the first one.

Comment: @johnelemans that was it! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not break the inner loop when the value of a node from the first list is found.

Also within the inner loop you do not repositioning the second list to its beginning.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int contains( list l1, list l2 )
{
    int check = 1;

    for ( ; check && l1 != NULL; l1 = l1->next )
    {
        check = 0;

       for ( link current = l2; !check && current != NULL; current = current->next )
       {
           if ( l1->data == current->data ) check = 1;
       }
    }

    return check;
}
```

The function does not check whether duplicated values are stored in the first list.

Pay attention that defining such a typedef as

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} *list;
```

is a bad idea. If you will need a pointer to a constant node you can not write

```
const link node;
```

because it means

```
struct node * const node;
```

not

```
const struct node *node;
```